# Game video - same content in different sizes

Tags: video

This is more on presenting your content on app store rather than coding.

I wonder how people can capture the same gameplay video in different format.

I mean, if I have iPad and iPhone, the logical way to do it is to capture the gameplay at both device. But my game is like Bejeweled, which the tiles will be spawned randomly, so how do other people do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake it.

A trailer for a software distribution platform can be one of the most important pieces of marketing material, so it can be well worth the time to invest attention to detail and make sure it shows the customer exactly what you want to show them when you want to show it.

Program a "demo mode" in which your game plays automatically and where the random events happen in exactly the way you want them to happen to present the gameplay in the most attractive way.

By the way: Do you know those "gameplay trailers" where developers present games by playing them while commenting on the gameplay and then say something like *"I didn't expect this to happen, but this shows really well how the game handles..."* - they are lying. They expected it because it was pre-scripted.

Comment: I gone into study quite a fair bit of video and that is what I found out too. In fact, some just use back the same video but edit it with video editor into video format.

Answer (score 0):

For what I see, the question is about being able to have the same and repeatable gameplay on different devices/screens/etc.

Usually the game can be instrumented to perfectly repeat itself.

For example randoms can be replaced with a pseudo-randoms - perfectly predicatable and repeating.

Physic simulations and floating-point math can be another source of differences. Usually it is kept out of the games logic, so only the details of visual effects are a bit different, but the games inner logic is the same.